# git checkout master returns error when switching from mybranch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

I was pushing code to `master` branch and switching to `mybranch` to fix bugs. Everything worked fine when using `$git checkout master` and `$git checkout mybranch`!

The problem is that I once typed `git checkout origin` instead of `git checkout master` when I wanted to switch from `mybranch` into `master`. Now, every time I want to return to `master` branch I get this error:

```
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

My question is: how can I get back to `master` branch using `$git checkout master` command?

Comment: Run `git branch -a` and cut-and-paste its output into your question, to help others figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first to not use `git checkout` but [`git switch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309) instead

That `switch` command won't try to find a file named "`master`" but will only consider the branch named `master`.
This assumes Git 2.23+ (August 2019)